# Sending form with vee-validate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vee-validate, vue-script-setup

I have following problem:
The error messages are always shown and when I click 'submit' nothing happens. I use vee-validate and composition API script setup. Project build with Vite. There is the code:

App.vue (parent component)

```
<script setup>

const cars = [
...
];

const required = (value) => {
  const requiredMessage = "This field is required!";
  if (value === undefined || value === null) return requiredMessage;
  if (!String(value).length) return requiredMessage;

  return true;
};

const minLength = (number, value) => {
   if (String(value).length < number) return 'Please type at least ' + number + ' characters'
  return true;
};

const validationSchema = {
  name: (value) => {
    const req = required(value)
    if (req !== true) return req
    const min = minLength(3, value)
    if (min !== true) return min

    return true
  },



  car: (value) => {
    const req = required(value)
    if (req !== true) return req

    return true
  },
};

const { value: name } = useField("name");
const { value: car } = useField("car");

const { handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
  validationSchema,
});

const submit = handleSubmit ( values => {
  console.log('submit', values)
})
</script>

<template>
  <form @submit="submit">
    <BaseInput
      v-model="name"
      type="text"
      :error="errors.name"
    ></BaseInput>
    <BaseSelect
      v-model="car"
      :cars="cars"
      :error="errors.car"
    ></BaseSelect>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

and BaseInput (child):

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: { type: [String, Number], default: "" },
  label: String,
  type: { type: String, default: "text" },
  error: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
});

const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);

function updateValue(value) {
  emit("update:modelValue", value);
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <label for="name">{{ label }}</label>
    <input
      name="name"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      :type="props.type"
      :value="props.modelValue"
      v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)"
    />
    <p>{{ error }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Code for BaseSelect is almost same. I just want to prevent form from submitting invalid data and show errors on blur event.

Comment: You should call `useForm` before any call to `useField`

Comment: Also from version [4.6.0](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/releases/tag/v4.6.0) you should use [useFieldModel API](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/v4.6.0/26c828e21495c485d489ea1319575d9b5c271801) for your use-case. `useField` is intended to be used inside custom input components (like your `BaseInput`)

Comment: @MichalLevý thank you very much! I'm also trying to validate inputs on blur events. But I don't know where to add this: 'events: 'blur'